# How to avoid interpolation of sensitive variables for a bat command in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, string-interpolation

on Linux you can replace the double quotes by single quotes to avoid interpolation.

```
// WRONG!
sh("curl -u ${EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR}:${EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW} https://example.com/")

// CORRECT!
sh('curl -u $EXAMPLE_CREDS_USR:$EXAMPLE_CREDS_PSW https://example.com/')
```

On Windows however, I'm not getting this to work.

Next command will work:

```
bat "mvn ${MAVENARGS} package -Ddlc=${DLC}"
```

But next command doesn't work:

```
bat 'mvn $MAVENARGS package -Ddlc=$DLC'
```

So how do you do this for a bat script?

Comment: Think I found the solution here https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-63254 . Probably was confused between ${} in Groovy and $ on Linux. Trying out %% now.

Comment: Yes you found it, `%var%` needs to be use to replace tha `$var`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be

```
bat 'mvn %MAVENARGS% package -Ddlc=%DLC%'
```

On Windows.